# Standalone component NG8001: 'component' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

This is my standalone component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent {

}
```

and this is where i have imported it (in  admin module)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin-routing.module';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from '../components/navbar/navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UsersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    NavbarComponent,
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

In my usercomponent.html template i did

```
<p>users works!</p>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

When I run ng serve I got

`error NG8001: 'app-navbar' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2 `

I would like to know why I have this error and how to fix it
Thanks !

Comment: I've resolved my problem. In app-routing.module.ts I put `{path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin-routing.module').then(m => m.AdminRoutingModule)}` instead of `{path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)}` I've lazy loaded AdminRouting instead of AdminModule.

Answer (score 0):

If NavbarComponent is part of another module, on that module you have to export the component using exports[], and then import the module, not the component on AdminModule.

If it is not part of other module, you have to include the component on declarations[] not on imports[].

Comment: Hi, NavbarComponent is not part of another module, it's a standalone component, so I can't include on declarations[]

Comment: I missed the standalone part... every thing seams fine then if you are using Angular 15

Comment: Yes I'm on angular 15.